# How do I export a OneNote 2013 page as an image (png or jpeg)?

Tags: images, microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2013

I use OneNote 2013 on a Samsung slate with a pen to take mind-maps in meetings (i.e. like these paper ones http://www.flickr.com/search/?q=mindmap+scan&m=tags&w=27141279%40N00 )

How do I export one of these as an image (png or jpeg)?

I tried exporting as an mht web page but there are several images in that I'd have to glue back together. How do I just save a page as a single image?

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you can do:

1. Save you note in XPS format.
   For that go to: File -> Export -> Select what you need under "Export Current:" (you'll most likely just need "Page") -> Select "XPS(*.xps)" under "Select Format" and click "Export"
2. Use any of the online conversion tools, like [Online image converter to JPEG](http://image.online-convert.com/convert-to-jpg) to convert your XPS file to JPEG

Multi-page XPS notes will be converted to several JPEG files, one file per a page in a note. Upon conversion you'll get a ZIP file containing all JPEG files.

Comment: Or just print to the Office XPS Document Writer.

Answer (score 2):

Better if:

1. Select the area on the screen which you want to make a jpeg of.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.
3. Open MS Paint and paste it there.
4. Export to JPEG or PNG.

That works with Photoshop too.

Comment: They are too big for this

Comment: Excellent, no need to install anything, not a sequence of steps, you can paste to Paint, PPT, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it by exporting it to a .mhtml file, opening it with Internet Explorer(Chrome and Firefox failed at displaying the document correctly), and then printing the page using [GreenShot](https://getgreenshot.org/) with the **Ctrl+Shift+PrntScrn** shortcut.

This was the only way I found to prevent it from generating A4-sized pages, which would later need to be puzzled together.